# select2 drodropdown isnt triggered when an already selected option is being selected again

Tags: jquery, reactjs, select, onchange

im new to react and in the application im working the the select dropdown change is not triggering....searchLedgerNames function is written inside useEffect so whenever the items in dropdown are changing the useeffect triggers and calls that function...but the problem here is whenver i go back to already selected item in the dropdown nothing is changing

```
      useEffect(() => {
        setLedgerDates();
        searchLedgerNames();
        if (props != undefined && props.location.state != undefined) {
            //some functionality of setting data
         }, [props]);


    function searchLedgerNames() {
      
        $('.ledger').select2({
            placeholder: "Select Ledger",
            multiple: false,
            width: '100%',
            tags: false,
            allowClear: true,
            ajax: {
                url: config.searchLedgerNames,
                type: 'GET',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        'searchName': params.term,
                        'token': UserInfo.getToken()
                    };
                },
               
                processResults: function (data) {
                   
                    if (data.status == 1) {      
                    return {
             
                        results: $.map(data.ledgerMap, function (item) {
                           // console.log("results are "+JSON.stringify(item))
                            return {
                                text: item.ledgerName,
                                    id: item.supplierOrCustomerId,
                                    ledgerType: item.ledgerType
                            }
                        })
                    };
                }
            }
            },
            templateResult: function (result) {
                
                return result.text;
            },
            templateSelection: function (selection) {
                
                if (selection != undefined) {
                    UserInfo.setLedgerId({key:selection.id, value:selection.text});
                    if (selection.ledgerType != undefined) {
                        UserInfo.setLedgerType(selection.ledgerType);
                        calculateLedgerService({key:selection.id, value:selection.text}, 
                        selection.ledgerType, new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en- 
                        GB').format(UserInfo.getLedgerFromDate()), 
                       new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(UserInfo.getLedgerToDate()));
                    }
                }
                return selection.text;
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3
        })
    }

    function calculateLedgerService(ledgerId, ledgerType, finStartYear,
              finEndYear) {
                console.log("Came inside calculateLedgerService")
                //some code to display data
                            }
```

inside render

```
                <select className="select2 form-control required ledger" 
                isSearchable={true} isMulti={false}
                components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
                value={UserInfo.getLedgerId()} required
                >
                </select>
```

Comment: Should your `onClick` in the `select` not be a `onChange`?

Comment: tried with onChange first....but even if i dnt write any onChange or onClick its working solely based on the jquery written and called in useeffect...but the problem is it gets triggered with change in the options in the dropdown sometimes and sometimes doesnt....unable to understand this unpredictable behaviour.....new to react so i thought may be im missing something here...